# Is 'appeasement' a negative word?

Tags: meaning

I'm not English. What I want to know is whether 'appeasement' is generally felt negatively by British people. Thanks

Comment: Why would you think so? In what context?

Comment: It is negative in the context of the start of [WWII and Neville Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Agreement). Otherwise it is neutral.

Comment: Please spare us this British people thing. FYI, this type of word (Latin and Greek "abstract") usually mean the same thing in all varieties of English.

Comment: Lambie, what have you got against we British people?

Comment: Indian Prime Minister Mr. Modi's tagline in the first tenure was "Development of all; appeasement to none."

Comment: @Mitch I think it may well have been the policy of the Chamberlain government, because of its ultimate failure, that attached negativity to the word. Historical events, and social changes, can greatly influence vocabulary. Think of the word "coronavirus". It is now almost synonymous with plague. Two years ago the word would not have suggested anything serious at all - quite the opposite eg. "the common cold is harmless - its only a coronavirus".

Answer (score 2):

I think this word is definitely negative because of its
strong association with the period before WWII when Britain, under Neville Chamberlain's Conservative government was acquiescent towards the Nazi regime, in the hope of avoiding war. This policy became known as *Appeasement*.

[There is a parallel in my own culture: the 不抵抗政策 (no-confrontation policy) during the Republic of China, when we did little against the Japanese Invasion. It's called 绥靖政策 (lit. appeasement policy) in Chinese.]

Because of this association the word generally bears negative connotations.

**Edit by WS2** This is already an excellent answer but I include below the OED entry which simply confirms the point that Jeremiah Hsu has made. And I was very interested to read that there was a similar word in Chinese, whose transformation belongs to the same era.

Prior to 1938 the word simply implied "to calm something down" - as will be evident from the examples given. It is now only ever used disparagingly - at least in Britain. **Note especially how Churchill, the person at the centre of the word's denigration in the late 1930s, had used it in the 1920s.**

> 4. Freely used in political contexts in the 20th century, and since 1938 often used disparagingly with allusion to the attempts at
>    conciliation by concession made by Mr. Neville Chamberlain, the
>    British Prime Minister, before the outbreak of war with Germany in
>    1939; by extension, any such policy of pacification by concession to
>    an enemy.

> 1919   Gen. Smuts' Messages to Empire: Problem of Peace 14
> In our policy of European settlement the appeasement of
> Germany..becomes one of cardinal importance. 1920   W. S. Churchill
> Let. 24 Mar. in World Crisis (1929) IV. xvii. 378   Here again I
> counsel prudence and appeasement. Try to secure a really
> representative Turkish governing authority, and come to terms with it.
> 1929   J. M. Keynes in Nation & Athenæum 9 Mar. 782/2   Apart from
> Russia, Mr. Churchill appears, in a degree to which public opinion has
> done much less than justice, as an ardent and persistent advocate of
> the policy of appeasement—appeasement in Germany, in Ireland, in
> Turkey. 1934   Ld. Lothian Let. in Times 4 May 15/5   A limitation of
> armaments by political appeasement. 1936   A. Eden in Hansard Commons
> 5th Ser. CCCX. 1446   I assure the House that it is the appeasement of
> Europe as a whole that we have constantly before us. 1937   W. K.
> Hancock Survey Brit. Commonw. Affairs I. 262   Equality and
> Appeasement, 1926–1936. 1938   Encycl. Brit. Bk. of Year 1938 194/1
> Economic appeasement must precede any world-wide political
> appeasement. 1938   Times 3 Oct. 13/2   The policy of international
> appeasement must of course be pressed forward... There must be
> appeasement not only of the strong but of the weak... With the policy
> of appeasement must go the policy of preparation—preparation not so
> much for war as against war. 1939   Ann. Reg. 1938 10   One of the new
> Foreign Minister's first steps was to extend to Germany the methods of
> appeasement—as the Prime Minister was fond of calling them—which were
> now being tried with Italy. 1939   New Statesman 29 July 165/1
> First, provided that there is a Russian pact, proposals that now smell
> of appeasement in the most dangerous sense at once become proper and,
> indeed, the only possible policy.

Comment: I have down voted because of the *I think this word is definitely negative because of its strong association with the period before WWII* The answer relies on a small cultural blip. There were many who agreed with Chamberlain particularly in a Britain that had no taste for war and was ill-prepared for one. (Article Wall Street Journal - https://www.wsj.com/articles/appeasement-review-what-were-they-thinking-11572619353) The word itself is to be understood contextually, and is therefore neutral.

Comment: @Greybeard There were undoubtedly many who agreed with Chamberlain at the time (though what that has to do with the way in which the word is used today I fail to see). However absolutely nobody nowadays believes the policy of *appeasement* was a good one - well there may be one or two. And without any question whatever the word in Britain today is treated with derision - as indeed is Chamberlain. Though many historians argue that his "peace in our time" negotiation bought Britain valuable time for rearmament.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mitch says in the comments, if *appeasement* is used in a political context, it has a negative valence.

See the OED definition:

> #### appeasement, n.
>
> 4. Freely used in political contexts in the 20th century, and since 1938 often used disparagingly with allusion to the attempts at conciliation by concession made by Mr. Neville Chamberlain, the British Prime Minister, before the outbreak of war with Germany in 1939; by extension, any such policy of pacification by concession to an enemy.

In current usage, it would be hard to escape this association.